# Arrange achor buttons in coulmn when resposive but display inline property is already applied on full sized screen

Tags: css, css-position, display

When the button active is clicked it is replaced by deactive button and vice versa this is going all good in size greater than 768px but when the screen size is smaller than 768px the button active is not replaced by deactive button rather the two-button appears at a different position in toggling on the small screen
**I think changes should be in display property when the screen is <=768px**  that it adjust it in a way that in toggling the button replaces each other in exactly the same position as it is working on big screen.

**My code:**

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.activeBtn').forEach(btn => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.closest('tr').classList.remove('active');
  });
});

document.querySelectorAll('.deactiveBtn').forEach(btn => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.closest('tr').classList.add('active');
  });
});
```

```css
tr a.activeBtn {
  display: none;
}

tr a.deactiveBtn {
  display: inline;
}

tr.active a.activeBtn {
  display: inline;
}

tr.active a.deactiveBtn {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="detailsCategory">
  <div class="recentCategory">
    <div class="card-header">
      <h2>Categories </h2>
      <a href="#" class="catBtn">Add Categories</a>
    </div>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td class="serial">#</td>
          <td>ID</td>
          <td>Categories</td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr class="active">
          <td class="serial">1</td>
          <td>4202211</td>
          <td>Men</td>
          <td class="statusButtons">
            <span><a href="#" class='status activeBtn' >Active</a></span>&nbsp;
            <span><a href="#" class='status deactiveBtn'>Deactive</a></span>&nbsp;
            <span><a href="#" class='status editBtn'>Edit</a></span>&nbsp;
            <span><a href="#" class='status deleteBtn'>Delete</a></span>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The two-lines-issue happens because you only hide the anchor in the span, but not the span itself...

Comment: biberman I have tried hiding span but the issue is not solved still

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have protected spaces `&nbsp;` after each span and therefor the line isn't empty and therefor isn't hidden. To prevent the issue you have to omit these. You could instead define a margin for the spans:

```
.statusButtons span {
  margin-right: 3px;
}
```

**Working example:**

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.activeBtn').forEach(btn => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.closest('tr').classList.remove('active');
  });
});

document.querySelectorAll('.deactiveBtn').forEach(btn => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.closest('tr').classList.add('active');
  });
});
```

```css
tr a.activeBtn {
  display: none;
}

tr a.deactiveBtn {
  display: inline;
}

tr.active a.activeBtn {
  display: inline;
}

tr.active a.deactiveBtn {
  display: none;
}

.statusButtons span {
  margin-right: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="detailsCategory">
  <div class="recentCategory">
    <div class="card-header">
      <h2>Categories </h2>
      <a href="#" class="catBtn">Add Categories</a>
    </div>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td class="serial">#</td>
          <td>ID</td>
          <td>Categories</td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr class="active">
          <td class="serial">1</td>
          <td>4202211</td>
          <td>Men</td>
          <td class="statusButtons">
            <span><a href="#" class='status activeBtn' >Active</a></span>
            <span><a href="#" class='status deactiveBtn'>Deactive</a></span>
            <span><a href="#" class='status editBtn'>Edit</a></span>
            <span><a href="#" class='status deleteBtn'>Delete</a></span>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I applied the display none property on span and removed the &nbsp and yay it worked  so happy:)))

Comment: If that answers your question you should mark it as accepted (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).